# AsyncTask's onPostExecute gets called: But doInBackground Does Not

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm having a bizarre problem and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or something.
For some reason, my AsyncTask won't call doInBackground but it calls onPostExecute(). It's essential that this AsyncTask gets called because it initializes a variable I will need throughout the rest of the app.

I have a nested class in my main activity that extends AsyncTask. This class takes care of downloading file names from the user's Dropbox account:

```
protected class FilesLister extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long>
{
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        Log.i("Entries", "We believe Entries has some values now.");
        ArrayList<Entry> theFiles = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        try
        {
            Entry entries = mDBApi.metadata("/", 20000, null, true, null);
            for (Entry e : entries.contents)
            {
                Log.i("Hm", e.fileName());
                if (!e.isDeleted)
                {
                    if(!e.isDir)
                    {
                        theFiles.add(e);
                    }
                }
            }
            theEntries = theFiles.toArray(new Entry[theFiles.size()]);
        } catch (DropboxException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("Now", "Calling refresh.");
        refresh();
    }
}
```

Like you can see, onPostExecute calls a method called refresh(). refresh() is implemented as follows:

```
public void refresh()
{
    //Sort all this files by last modified date.
    Arrays.sort(theEntries, new Comparator<Entry>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry firstFile, Entry secondFile)
        {
            //"EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss ZZZZZ"
            SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss ZZZZZ");
            try
            {
                Date date1 = (Date)formater.parse(firstFile.modified);
                Date date2 = (Date)formater.parse(secondFile.modified);
                return date1.compareTo(date2);
            } catch (ParseException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
    //Now we create a String[] array to hold the names of all the fetched files...
    ArrayList<String>txtFilesNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = theEntries.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        //Loops goes from top to bottom so the latest file appears at the top of the ListView.
        txtFilesNames.add(theEntries[i].fileName());
    }
    actualFileNames = txtFilesNames.toArray(new String[txtFilesNames.size()]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, actualFileNames);
    lv.setAdapter(ad);
}
```

I know refresh() is being called for two reasons: LogCat logs "Calling refresh." and then the app crashes because of a NullPointerException. The null pointer exceptions is thrown because theEntries is indeed null, and it will be null unless doInBackground() gets called. And I know doInBackground is never called due to the null pointer and because the Log I put on it's body never gets called. So what could cause my doInBackground() method not to get called? If it matters, I execute the AsyncTask in my onResume method, and I don't execute any other AsyncTasks in either onCreate or onStart.

Comment: first thing first why you are using  AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long>  if your doinbackground is not intended to return any value why not  AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>???

Comment: Set a breakpoint in doInBackground and step through the code with the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure doInBackground isn't getting called? There are plenty of other ways which could cause theEntries to be null. For instance, an exception here:

```
        Entry entries = mDBApi.metadata("/", 20000, null, true, null);
        for (Entry e : entries.contents)
        {
            Log.i("Hm", e.fileName());
            if (!e.isDeleted)
            {
                if(!e.isDir)
                {
                    theFiles.add(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

could cause theEntries to be null. Also, I think you could do this a better way. Instead of setting theEntries within doInBackground (which is in a different thread than your object was created in) you should instead have that function return the entries which will pass them to onPostExecute.I believe the code would look like this:

```
protected class FilesLister extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Entry[]>
{
    @Override
    protected Entry[] doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        Log.i("Entries", "We believe Entries has some values now.");
        Entry[] entriesReturn = null;
        ArrayList<Entry> theFiles = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        try
        {
            Entry entries = mDBApi.metadata("/", 20000, null, true, null);
            for (Entry e : entries.contents)
            {
                Log.i("Hm", e.fileName());
                if (!e.isDeleted)
                {
                    if(!e.isDir)
                    {
                        theFiles.add(e);
                    }
                }
            }
            entriesReturn = theFiles.toArray(new Entry[theFiles.size()]);
        } catch (DropboxException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return entriesReturn;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Entry[] result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("Now", "Calling refresh.");
        refresh(result);
    }
}
```

Then in your refresh method do the assignment.. Also you should check for null in the refresh method.

Comment: Absolutely certain it isn't getting called. I caught the initial exception for now and am close to figuring it out. You made me think and I wonder why I didn't notice this earlier, but turns out a DropboxException is being thrown, hence that block is not reaching its end. Regardless, I won't sing victory just yet, but thanks a lot for pointing out another possible exception. I'm doing progress now.

Comment: Yep, you pointing out that exception definitely helped me! I wonder why I didn't notice it was being caught when I wrote it myself. Thanks a bunch for your help. The problem was that my phone had no connection to the internet for some reason, hence the DropboxException getting caught and not allowing the block to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been posted by others (see sidebar for related questions). As of now, there is still no solution for this issue. I have ran into this myself, and after struggling for a few days I accepted this as a bug.
What you could do is use `Activity.runOnUiThread()`. It will fix this issue you're having, but not the issue with `AsyncTasks`. It's how I worked around this issue.

Comment: Yeah, I saw others posted this question but I didn't saw anyone who specifically had onPostExecute called without calling doInBackground. I saw people saying it wouldn't run, and others that onPreExecute would run (which would make sense), but it makes no sense to call onPostExecute when doInBackground hasn't been called. I appreciate your help, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

you able to check that  doInBackground() is call or not in onPostExecute() by this way.

```
 protected Long doInBackground(String... params)
    {
   /////your code...
        return 200;
    }
  protected void onPostExecute(Long result)
    {
       if(result==200)
{
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("Now", "Calling refresh.");
        refresh();
}
    }
```

I am not sure that your entries gives null value or not. In this way you able to know doInBackground() is execute or not.

I think it gives some help .

Thanks.